# Stream image from server (Java) to client (Javascript) using websockets

Tags: java, javascript, servlets, websocket, client-server

I have done this before with a vanilla servlet where on the doGet() method I used a InputStream and OutputStream and set the content type and my png would appear in the browser as fast as I could generate it on the server.

My goal is to have an image be drawn piece by piece (as fast as the connection allows) as it is generated on the server. I do not want to generate the entire image on the server and then serve it to the browser. Can I just reuse my code that writes my image from the server, do I need to handle the incoming image stream on the client side? I just want the image to be shown.

I really wish http://binaryjs.com/ had java server support (I am using tomcat).

Comment: I would stream the base64 encoded string through websocket and concatenate it on the client side. Sounds doable, but I'm not sure how a half-complete base64 encoded image would look like.

Comment: Someone has to have tried this. I am hoping that you would get a half-complete image when half the data is streamed over.

Comment: Not necessarily. First I would try that manually, cut a base64 string in half and see how it turns out (in best scenario half of the image will be shown). If that's what you wanted, streaming the pieces and concatenating it on the client shouldn't be hard.

Comment: Is there any example code for this? I cannot find any and I am not familiar with converting images to base64 and piecing it back together in javascript.

Comment: This is a really specific use-case involving different technologies and concepts, I don't think there is an example for all this. But I'm sure you will find for websockets and java base64 image encoding.

Comment: Did you get any answer for this ??

Comment: This was a super long time ago, but I think I just ended up sending data in chunked format and interpreting it as a png or jpg on the client side.